# Eliminate the entropic contribution in the free energy of dimerization between two molecules in umbrella sampling

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs

For my set-up to compute the free energy of dimerization between two molecules in a solvent using umbrella sampling, I can see that there is an entropic contribution since I have used distance as a reaction coordinate. How can we eliminate this entropic contribution from the free energy profile? Thanks.